# How to derive Torque formular $\tau = \omega\times I \omega + I\dot{\omega}$

Tags: mathematical-physics

Here is the formula I am trying to derive:
$$\tau = \omega\times I \omega + I\dot{\omega}$$
where $\tau$ is the torque. $\dot{\omega}$ is the angular acceleration. $I$ is the moment of inertia. $\omega$ is the angular velocity.

This is what I tried. I know that the angular momentum:
$$L = I\omega $$
So
$$\tau = \frac{dL}{dt} = \frac{d(I\omega)}{dt} =  \frac{dI}{dt}\omega + \frac{d\omega}{dt}I $$
$$\tau =  \frac{dI}{dt}\omega + \dot{\omega}I $$

It is close, but I can not go further. I only know that $I = m r^2$, and $\frac{dI}{dt}$ does not give me the result I wanted. I must have missed something.

Comment: Unfortunately no, here $I$ is a matrix and is not equal to $mr^2$. Are you familiar with the formula $I = RI_{\rm{body}}R^T$?

Comment: No, looks like a matrix decomposition. Yeah, that makes sense now, I think I can look into that.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body_dynamics#Rotation_in_three_dimensions